# Node.Js - Return 1 if no matching document is found in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongodb-query, nosql

Following query is written in MongoDB, I want to modify it such that when there is no matching record it should return 1.

**Code :**

```
 db.collection("uses").find({users:uid}).toArray((err,response) => {
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
    if(response){
        res.json(uid);
    }
    else{
        res.json("1");
    }    
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[.find()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/index.html) would return a cursor & since you're using `.toArray()` on a cursor then it would return an array of objects/documents if any matched or else an empty array, So in your below code adding `response.length` should work :

```
 db.collection("uses").find({users:uid}).toArray((err,response) => {
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
    if(response && response.length){
        res.json(uid);
    }
    else{
        res.json("1");
    }    
})
```